# perl sometimes skips for loop without a pattern

Tags: perl, for-loop, sqlite

I have trouble with a for loop in perl. I want to get Information of the beginning and the end of a sequence of DNA from a database (in SQLite) and then want to add the sequence to the database from a file that contains the whole genome of my organism. So basically I want a piece of text from a  text file and I know the position the piece starts and the position it ends. So what I did is, I broke down the text to letters, put them into an array and just make up a new array by picking all elements inbetween my start and end point. And for some reason it does not do that for every row I fetch from the database. 
What I did so far to solve the problem: I looked if all my variables exist, and they do. It is to my knowledge not a database problem nor a problem with my input file. So why does the skript not go through every for loop?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

#... connecting to db, array @all defined etc. works all fine

while(@row= $sth-> fetchrow_array){
        $start=$row[0]; #works, is always defined
        $end=$row[1]; #works, is always defined
        $id=$row[2]; #works, is always defined
        print OUT $id; #works
        for ($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++){ #seems that this loop is sometimes ignored (without any pattern)?
            $count++;
            print OUT $count; #is printed out continuously, but not for every $id, some lines in the OUT file are just empty after the $id
            $line=$all[$i]; #this is what I actually want to do
            push (@prom, $line);
        }
        print OUT "\n"; #works
#and then go on and do things with @prom        
}
```

Comment: It seems not actual code you use. You have nicely strict/warnings in place, but you don't declare your variables at all. Such script can't run.

Comment: And. You don't have array `@all` but you try to read from it. When you use actual strict/warnings in your code, you can't miss such errors.

Comment: uh sorry I thought I was supposed to only post the piece of code that doenst work. I can of course post the whole skript

Comment: Recommended way is to refactor out faulty part as independent working example. Most times it solves problem by itself ;-)

Comment: You should post code that works and demonstrates the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Rather than converting a string to an array of letter then picking array elements you might use Perl's substring function `substr`, see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html

Comment: ok I am really sorry but I am stuck now, how am I supposed to write working code for a database and file only I have...?

Comment: No, the more important question is - how is anyone _else_ supposed to?

Comment: yeah true ^^ I will try to work that out for my next question, for this one the substr worked. I didn't know that one, so thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, the only reason your `for` loop can be skipped is if `$end <= $start`.

I suggest you change your `for` loop to

```
for my $i ($start .. $end-1)
```

and immediately preceding it write

```
warn "Line being skipped: $start ... $end" if $end <= $start
```

That way you will be able to see your erroneous data.